# When trying to open Swagger-UI getting only a json Response

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui

I am getting the following response when requesting for Swagger doc in a Web API project,even the same response getting from Azure.

[image]

Can any one help me to get the Swagger UI.

Comment: Which framework are you using - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, etc.? Please post your configuration code.

Comment: i am using Swashbuckle.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try to request the Swagger-UI through a different url, eg.../swagger/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I am not working with .NET here and I have no Idea about your setup, but did you (for example) copied swagger-ui resources to your webdir?
It looks like you are calling swagger interface directly and not swagger-ui (which is something different).

https://swagger.io/swagger-ui/

from Swagger-Ui Documentation:

**Step 1**: Go to the GitHub repository of the Swagger UI project

**Step 2**: Clone or download the zip file of the repository

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

**Usage**
**Step 1**: Go to the folder containing the Swagger UI project in your local machine

**Step 2**: Open the dist folder

**Step 3**: Run the dist/index.html file on a browser or place the dist folder inside your server.

**Step 4**: The Swagger UI will now be live in the browser, with the default rendering of the Swagger Petstore. The JSON specification of the Swagger Petstore can be found here - http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

**Note**: Please remember that to load a specification and execute the UI’s try out requests, you would need to have enabled CORS (read below)

**Step 5**: You can mention the YAML or JSON path of any existing specification hosted on a server in the field on the top navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL for the UI would be `https://localhost:44390/swagger/ui/index`

Answer (score 0):

Check if swagger is configured to use any custom route or prefix. In this case the UI URL would be url:port/route-prefix/index.html. Route prefix empty = url:port/index.html.